# MYSQL Subtables Grouping

Tags: mysql, grouping

If I have 2 tables:

```
A     B
joe   1
joe   2
kevin 3

B C
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
3 3
```

What is the best way to get the subgroups when I search for column A?

i.e. for joe, i want to return `1:{1,2,3}` and `2:{2,3}`.

I know that I can iterate through multiple `SELECT * FROM` queries, but is there a way to do it in one query?

As a followup, 
If I had a third table,

C D
1 x
2 y
3 z

How do I table 2 and table 3 together and then group by B?

I tried

select
  tbla.id, tbla.name, group_concat(tblb.value)
from tbla
left join tblb
  on tbla.id = tblb.a_id
group by tbla.id 
left join tb1c
  on tb1b.id=tb1c.id

and it does not seem to work

Comment: You want to return data `1:{1,2,3}` format?

Comment: figured it out. it would be something like SELECT t1 LEFT JOIN (Select group_concat(t2) LEFT JOIN t3 group by t2.id ) as newt2 on t1.id=t2.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

E.g.

```
select
  tbla.id, tbla.name, group_concat(tblb.value)
from tbla
left join tblb
  on tbla.id = tblb.a_id
group by tbla.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TableB.C) as iResult
FROM   tableB INNER JOIN tableA
        on TableB.B = tableA.B
WHERE   tableA.A = 'joe'
```